# In Python 3, convert np.array object type to float type, with variable number of object element

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I have a np.array with dtype as object. Each element here is a np.array with dtype as float and shape as (2,2) --- in maths, it is a 2-by-2 matrix. My aim is to obtain one 2-dimenional matrix by converting all the object-type element into float-type element. This can be better presented by the following example.

```
dA = 2  # dA is the dimension of the following A, here use 2 as example only
A = np.empty((dA,dA), dtype=object)  # A is a np.array with dtype as object
A[0,0] = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])   # each element in A is a 2-by-2 matrix
A[0,1] = A[0,0]*2
A[1,0] = A[0,0]*3
A[1,1] = A[0,0]*4
```

My aim is to have one matrix B (the dimension of B is 2*dA-by-2*dA). The form of B in maths should be

```
B = 
    1 1 2 2
    1 1 2 2
    3 3 4 4
    3 3 4 4
```

If dA is fixed at 2, then things can be easier, because I can hard-code

```
a00 = A[0,0]
a01 = A[0,1]
a10 = A[1,0]
a11 = A[1,1]
B0 = np.hstack((a00,a01))
B1 = np.hstack((a10,a11))
B = np.vstack((B0,B1))
```

But in reality, dA is a variable, it can be 2 or any other integer. Then I don't know how to do it. I think nested for loops can help but maybe you have brilliant ideas. It would be great if there is something like cell2mat function in MATLAB. Because here you can see A[i,j] as a cell in MATLAB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using a numpy object array for `A`?  From what I can see, a list of lists, or even just a list with length 4, would work just as well.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, the reason is: in my program, "A" is a characteristic matrix of a system of 2 copper wires. See "A" as matrix, so its main diagonal blocks "A[0,0]" and "A[1,1]" are characteristics of wire 0 and wire 1, respectively; while the off-diagonal blocks are mutual impacts on those two wires, "A[0,1]" and "A[1,0]". These 4 blocks are calculated individually. After obtained them all, I want to assemble them in to one matrix "A".  Using the matrix index-style "[i,j]" is easier to program the whole computational process and easier to read for people with technical background.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  In that case, instead of a 2-d object array, I would use a 4-d array:  `A = np.empty((dA, dA, 2, 2))`.  I try to avoid object arrays as much as possible.  Many numpy and scipy functions don't work well with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick way.

Your `A`:

```
In [137]: A
Out[137]: 
array([[array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1]]), array([[2, 2],
       [2, 2]])],
       [array([[3, 3],
       [3, 3]]), array([[4, 4],
       [4, 4]])]], dtype=object)
```

Use [`numpy.bmat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bmat.html), but convert `A` to a python list first, so `bmat` does what we want:

```
In [138]: B = np.bmat(A.tolist())

In [139]: B
Out[139]: 
matrix([[1, 1, 2, 2],
        [1, 1, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 4, 4],
        [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

The result is actually a `numpy.matrix`.  If you need a regular numpy array, use the `.A` attribute of the `matrix` object:

```
In [140]: B = np.bmat(A.tolist()).A

In [141]: B
Out[141]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

---

Here's an alternative.  (It still uses `A.tolist()`.)

```
In [164]: np.swapaxes(A.tolist(), 1, 2).reshape(4, 4)
Out[164]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

In the general case, you would need something like:

```
In [165]: np.swapaxes(A.tolist(), 1, 2).reshape(A.shape[0]*dA, A.shape[1]*dA)
Out[165]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `vstack/hstack` could be written more compactly, and generally as

```
In [132]: np.vstack((np.hstack(a) for a in A))
Out[132]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

since `for a in A` iterates on the `rows` of `A`.

Warren suggests `np.bmat`, which is fine.  But if you look at the `bmat` code, you'll see that it just doing this kind of nested `concatenate` (expressed a row loop with `arr_rows.append(np.concatenate...)`).