# 2D python list of numpy arrays to 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Which is the most performant way
to convert something like that

```
problem = [ [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5])],
            [np.array([6,7,8]), np.array([9,10])]]
```

into

```
desired = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], 
                   [6,7,8,9,10]])
```

Unfortunately, the final number of columns and rows (and length of subarrays) is not known in advance, as the subarrays are read from a binary file, record by record.

Comment: So, the number of elems in each element of the list would be the same, like it's `5` here?

Comment: Does `bmat` work?

Comment: The number for each row is the same, so no padding or else is required.

Comment: Then, I guess the fastest one would be with a traditional loop, intialize output array and use `np.concatenate` iteratively to assign for each row as listed in [`@Carles Mitjans's solution`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40761137/3293881).

Comment: A similar question with answer by Warren: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128514/in-python-3-convert-np-array-object-type-to-float-type-with-variable-number-of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this:

```
print np.array([np.hstack(i) for i in problem])
```

Using your example, this runs in 0.00022s, wherease `concatenate` takes 0.00038s

You can also use `apply_along_axis` although this runs in 0.00024s:

```
print np.apply_along_axis(np.hstack, 1, problem)
```

Comment: looks good, but i believe that does it take 2 allocation processes? First for each row, and then every row gets copied into the large array?

Comment: Look at `bmat` code - an `hstack` for each row, and `vstack` to join the rows. If the list was flattened, you could use one `concatenate` and then reshape.  I don't think the time differences are significant.

Comment: `np.concatenate` seems to be faster than stacking or `bmat`:

   `problem = [  [np.array([.1]*5000)] * 5 ] * 10000`
    `solution = np.array([np.concatenate(x) for x in problem])`

Comment: Hstack uses concatenate.

Comment: maybe, but there'se a clear difference for me (python 3.5, numpy 1.11)

Comment: `hstack` adds the extra step of making sure all inputs are at least 1d.  Look at its code.  Here that extra step isn't needed.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
problem = [[np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5])],
        [np.array([6,7,8]), np.array([9,10])]]

print np.array([np.concatenate(x) for x in problem])
```